# Fitting exponential decay

Tags: python, scipy

I'm trying to solve the following linearized equation:

**ln⁡{1−y/y}=ln⁡(c)−b(x)**

Using python scipy curvefit or another similar method, could your please let me know how to do this?

Sample data:

```
x = [15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]

y = [0.78, 0.67, 0.56, 0.41, 0.31, 0.20]
```

code I have tried so far:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import pylab
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
import warnings   

def sigmoid(x,c,b):
    y = np.log(c)-b*x
    return y

def sigmoid_solve(y, c, b):
    x = (np.log(c)+np.log((1-y)/y))/b
    return x

y_new = []

x_data = [15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
y_data = [0.78, 0.67, 0.56, 0.41, 0.31, 0.20]


for data in y_data:
    y_new.append(np.log((1-data)/data))


popt, pcov = curve_fit(sigmoid, x_data, y_new)
ce50 = sigmoid_solve(0.5,popt[0],popt[1])

x = np.linspace(10,40,10)
y = 1/(1+np.exp(sigmoid(x, *popt)))
plt.plot(x, y, 'r',label='logistic exp curve fit')
plt.plot(x_data, y_data,'o',label='data plot')
plt.ylim(0, 1)
plt.xlim(10, 50)
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.savefig('test.png')
plt.close("all")
```

Is there a better way of solving this?

Comment: You mention curvefit, have you tried using it? Have a look at the example they provide on the reference page: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html

Answer (score 0):

I will not understand well your problem.

In this moment I will think on many ways. (Certainly I don't know if they are the best)

1.- I will take the function that you have.

**ln⁡{1−y/y}=ln⁡(c)−b(x)**

Anb if this the equation that you want solve (find the intersection of the curves),  I will do find the solution of ln⁡{1−y/y}-(ln⁡(c)−b(x))=0.

2.- If you want to know the best curve to fit the data, you will use a fit of a bezier curve, matplotlib already have some functions, look at here:

[Bézier example](http://matplotlib.org/users/path_tutorial.html#bezier-example)

3.- But if you want to solve the system (that it's an EDO I think) you will check at here, python have a lot of this:

[Scipy Integration and ODEs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/integrate.html)

And this:

[Solve Differential Equations in Python](http://apmonitor.com/che263/index.php/Main/PythonDynamicSim)

Cheers.

Antonio.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem in your code is the c parameter, since curve_fit tries using negatives values resulting in error. Unfortunately, I didn't find any reference in the docs as to how to 'bound' the output parameters (someone can improve this answer by pointing out how to do this). Try replacing c by log_c, which can have any value:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def sigmoid(x, log_c, b):
    return log_c - b * x

def sigmoid_solve(y, log_c, b):
    x = (log_c + np.log((1-y)/y))/b
    return x

x_data = np.array([15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20])
y_data = np.array([0.78, 0.67, 0.56, 0.41, 0.31, 0.20])
y_new = (np.log((1.0-y_data)/y_data))

popt, pcov = curve_fit(sigmoid, x_data, y_new)
ce50 = sigmoid_solve(0.5,popt[0],popt[1])

x = np.linspace(10,40,10)
y = 1/(1+np.exp(sigmoid(x, *popt)))

plt.plot(x, y, 'r',label='logistic exp curve fit')
plt.plot(x_data, y_data,'o',label='data plot')
plt.ylim(0, 1)
plt.xlim(10, 50)
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.savefig('test.png')
plt.close("all")
```

This code worked fine for me. Note also that if you use np.array instead of lists you can apply mathematical functions w/o looping.